# Accessing C# webservices from PHP

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I have several web-services that I need to regularly query for data.  These services were written in C#, and error out when I try to connect to them via mono.  I am able to connect to them via c# and get whatever data I need.  All data is in json, if that matters.

I have a php-based website that needs to be able to query these web-services.  I'm looking for the best way to get this data from C# to PHP.

My idea so far is to have c# write to a database, then query the db from PHP.  While this is an option, I'd prefer to be able to have php initiate the query, providing actual real-time data.

Comment: When you say "web services", do you mean proper SOAP based services? In that case they should be consumable by any language. Do you have a wsdl file for the service?

Comment: I do have (several) wsdl files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [PHP Soap Client](http://us.php.net/soapclient)

Comment: I'll give this a try.  Maybe I was making the problem harder than it has to be.  Thanks.

Comment: Checked all my services and they all work with this.  I'm gonna miss intellisense, and it looks like there's some tweaking to get proper ssl working, but ultimately it's going to same me a lot of time.  Thanks!